State space models and Kalman Filter
I have the following model specification:
$y_t = \mu_t + v_t,$
$\mu_{t+1|t} = \phi \, \mu_{t|t-1} + k\, v_t $
where v_t= y_t - mu_{t|t-1},    v_t|F_{t-1} ~ tv(0, sigma^2).
I was asked to provide the filtered estimates of mu_t or mu_{t|t-1} and to estimate the static parameters : phi, v, sigma^2.
I use the Kalman Filter . The generalstate space representation is :                             y_t = Z_t* alpha_t + G_t* epsilon_t.                                                                  alpha_{t+1} = T_t* alpha_t + H_t* eta_t
In this case: Z_t=1, T_t = phi, G_t= sigma_v , H_t= k*sigma_v, alpha_t= mu_t.
For the kalman Filter : v_t = y_t - Z_t* alpha_{t|t-1} # prediction error
F_t = Z_t * P_{t|t-1} Z_t' + G_t G_t' # variance of the prefiction error
alpha_{t|t} = alpha_{t|t-1} + P_t* Z_t'* F_t^-1 *vt # E[alpha_t| F_t]
P_{t|t} = P_{t|t-1} - P{t|t-1}*Z_T' * F_t^-1 Z_tP_t # V[alpha_t|F_t]
alpha_{t+1|t} = T_t* alpha_{t|t-1} + k_t *vt# updated state estimate
P_{t+1|t} = T_t* P_{t|t-1}* T_t'+ H_tQ_tH_t' - K_t * F_t *K_t'# updated state variance
Kalman gain K_t= T_t* P_{t|t-1}Z_t' F_t^-1
In order to compute the estimate for mu_{t|t}, do I just have to replace alpha_{t|t} = alpha_{t|t-1} + P_t* Z_t'* F_t^-1 *vt?
mu_{t|t} = mu_{t|t-1} + P_t* Z_t'* F_t^-1 *vt?

Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/348271

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have edited the first couple of lines to indicate that only a very small change to what you wrote is needed to produce nice looking results - just inserting a few $ and \ symbols does most of it; see the edit history to see how little needs to change. Please edit. Jarle Tufto's comment points you to more details if you need anything fancier.
